# image encryption using permutation technique in java

Tags: image, encryption

I am doing my project in java i.e image Encryption using pemutation in that where first i divided my image into the blocks.  I wanted to get permutate these blocks of images please help me

Comment: can you show any code or effort you have put ?

Comment: i used javax.imageio.ImageIO;  then i given the rows and coloums to divide them into blocks then i got the blocks of images then my next step is the blocks which i got i need to permutate those blocks how